# How to create representative training, validation, and test sets when working with time series data?

Tags: time-series, modeling, finance, train-test-split, representative

In my application, I am working with a relatively long time series of daily market index percentage returns (many years) and am trying to model the dependence structure of the returns from a pure time series perspective (if there is any) and analyse the probabilistic properties of the residuals after any dependence is removed or the original return series if there is no dependence between days. Technically, this is a univariate time series taking values in $(-1, \infty)$.

I have employed the commonly used framework of splitting my data into train, validation, and test sets such that chronological ordering is respected to evaluate my models and create hypotheses.

Specifically, I want to make sure that I'm paying attention to extreme values of my time series, say returns with with magnitude greater than or equal to 0.07. I'd like to make each of these  disjoint subsets of my whole time series representative of my larger sample, especially as it pertains to each subset having a similar percent of extreme returns. I'm trying to do this so I have enough data to create hypotheses and also enough unseen data to see if these hypotheses hold out-of-sample.

Let's assume there are 20 days in the whole time series of 25000 days where the return has absolute value greater than or equal to 0.07. Additionally let's say that half of these extreme values lie within the first 5000 days. The problem I run into is that these extreme days are not evenly spread across time meaning that I run into a tradeoff between having my subsets be representative of the larger sample and having sufficient data in my training set so as to be able to learn from this data independent of the extreme days as I would like to analyze "typical" days as well.

Any input or references on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more details on what "extreme values" and "observations" you're looking at, as well as what you're trying to predict/model? The tradeoff issue that you mention seems plausible, but it's hard to appreciate without details.

Comment: @chang_trenton Yes, no problem, updated the post now. Thanks for asking.

Comment: You have a single univariate time series for some financial market index (e.g., the DJIA or S&P 500) with a unit of analysis in days captured over a large number of years, correct? Given that, why would you want to create multiple sets of data from this univariate time series? Are you referring to using some sort of iterative bootstrap algorithm like random forests? Please clarify.

Comment: @MikeHunter I am wanting to split this time series so I am able to perform exploratory data analysis/model building/hypothesis creation on the training set, measuring out-of-sample performance for parameter tuning, model evaluation, etc. on the validation set, and evaluating final performance without re-tuning on the test set. I am also wanting to ensure that each set is representative of the whole set of observations so that I can evaluate the models/hypotheses and have somewhat of a guarantee on if the models/hypotheses will hold out-of-sample.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: For me the logic behind your proposed approach doesn't work. Why would you want to fix or hold anything constant in an exploratory stage? The variance in input data in any approximating, iterative algorithm is the basis for *evaluating final performance*, is it not? In other words, allow random draws to do their thing.

Comment: @MikeHunter I don't think that I'm describing what I'm trying to do very clearly. Given an observed time series of index returns, I want attempt to try to forecast future returns, either in a point or probabilistic manner. I am wanting to make sure that my model performs well in the presence of extreme and/or rare events that impact the time series and to approximate how well my model will do on future unseen data, I feel as if the data sets that I'm training on should be probabilistically similar, at least in the unconditional sense. I also cannot (to my knowledge) employ balancing that is...

Comment: usually used with cross validation on sets of i.i.d. observations as I think random resampling would work against the dependence structure of my time series data.

Comment: You've described what you're doing well enough and this comment doesn't change my observation. I continue to maintain that the logic is flawed. If you put your data into some iterative, approximating algorithm and run thousands of mini-models (using RFs as an example) then, by default, you will obtain many subsamples which conform to your quest to define a baseline. This paper https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-divide-and-conquer-algorithm-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/ describes them in computer science. In statistics they include bootstrap, jackknife, hierarchical bayes

Comment: @MikeHunter Okay, that makes sense, but the crux of what I am wanting to know is if there is a need to have distributionally-equivalent train, validation, and test sets for time series analysis/extreme event analysis and prediction evaluation, like say I wanted to build a classifier that used all the information up to that point and tried to predict if the next day would have a return with absolute value greater than 0.07.

Comment: Check out Sornette's book *Why Stock Markets Crash* for greater insights into your project. Like Taleb, he's an evangelist for extreme value models. Unlike Taleb, he's a statistician who's not gone over to the commercial, popularizing dark side. Also, his many papers at his ETH-Zurich Financial Risk Observatory will be informative. https://emeritus.er.ethz.ch/financial-crisis-observatory.html

Comment: With today's tech, there is no need to *have distributionally-equivalent train, validation, and test sets for time series analysis/extreme event analysis and prediction evaluation*.

Comment: Fair points and thank you for the detailed answers, I'll have to check these references out, I'm familiar with Taleb's work, but not too much of the others, thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147754/discussion-between-qmath-and-mike-hunter).